# Is there regex match at point?

Tags: search

I want to match a certain string (not even a regex!) at point. `re-search-forward` skips characters after the point.

With `char-after` it is possible to build a framework for matching a string at point. I hope there is an idiomatic way to match a string at point.

**UPDATE** alternatively I can `search-forward` and if:

```
old point - new point != string length
```

I miss match...

Or set `bound` to string length:

```
(search-forward str (+ (point) (length str)) nil)
```

Pity that `search-forward` moves pointer...

Comment: "(not even regex!)" directly conflicts with your title.  Do you want to match a regexp or not?

Comment: If you want to match a word you could use `thing-at-point` to get the word and then compare with `string=`.

Comment: "Pity that search-forward moves pointer..." - that's why `save-excursion` exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking to do this from lisp code? If so, you can use [`looking-at`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html#index-looking_002dat-4147):

> (looking-at REGEXP)
>
> Return t if text after point matches regular expression REGEXP. This
>   function modifies the match data that ‘match-beginning’, ‘match-end’
>   and ‘match-data’ access; save and restore the match data if you want
>   to preserve them.

For example, if point is right after the parenthesis in:

```
(looking-at "abc")abc
```

running `C-x C-e` will return `t`. However, doing the same if there's an x before `abc` will return nil:

```
(looking-at "abc")xabc
```

Comment: I think this is what OP is looking for. And if there are regexp-special chars in the string to match, and he doesn't wants them matched literally, then `(looking-at (regexp-quote "the-string-to-match"))`. And there is also `looking-at-p`. (Feel free to incorporate any of this into your answer if you like.)

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression to match `point` in emacs is `\=`.  Try e.g. `(search-forward-regexp "\\=blah")`.